# Best way to collect and store times and dates

Tags: c#, .net

This question might be a little ambiguous so I'll explain my goal and my previous implementation.  I'm looking for some advice on how to improve my implementation.

My application needs a certain set of days and times (hours and minutes) to be used for criteria later in the program.

The days and times are variable and depend on whether a user is a member of a particular group or not.

My previous implementation was to get the name of the group that was selected and then go to the web server and download the appropriate file which contained the day and time.  There was a file for each group.

The format of the text file was:

> Day,Day,Day,etc..HH,HH,MM,MM

It was then read into two separate arrays with the positions hardcoded. E.g. Index 0, 1,2 where days while 3,4 where hours and 5,6 where minutes.

This method also meant that I'd need a longer array for a group that had more days than another.

Obviously this was all very inefficient and the code wasn't very reusable or extendable.  I'd have to alter if a new group was introduced and it had more of less data in the text file.

Edit - due to the vagueness of the question I have included code:

This method is passed the group name in the fileName parameter of CollectQualifyingTimes.  The string looked like gtstimes.txt or gtsdates.txt or gectimes.txt or gecdates.txt

```
internal static class DownloadQualifyingTimes
 {
    //TimeDate Arrays
    public static readonly List<string> QDaysList = new List<string>();
    public static readonly List<int> QTimesList = new List<int>();

    private static StreamReader _reader;
    private static string _line;
    private static string _file;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Collects the Times
    /// </summary>
    public static void CollectQualifyingTimes(string fileName)
    {
        Logger.Debug("About to download the " + fileName + " Qualifying Times and Dates");

        FileDownload.DownloadOnlineFile(fileName);
        OpenQualifyingFile(fileName);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Open the qualifying file and read the values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static void OpenQualifyingFile(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            _file = Path + "\\" + fileName;

            using (_reader = new StreamReader(_file))
            {
                while ((_line = _reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (fileName.Contains("Times"))
                    {
                        QTimesList.Add(Convert.ToInt16(_line));
                        Logger.Debug("Times " + _line);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        QDaysList.Add(_line);
                        Logger.Debug("Days " + _line);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException exception)
        {
            Logger.Error(exception);
        }
    }
}



//The method that calls the Downloading class looks like this:
/// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="selectedLeague"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool QualificationTimeCheck(string selectedLeague)
    {
        var currentUtcTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        //Day check regardless of league
        if    (DownloadQualifyingTimes.QDaysList.Contains(currentUtcTime.DayOfWeek.ToString()))
        {
            Logger.Debug("Qualifying day condition meet");
            if (selectedLeague.IsOneOf("GTS", "CAT"))
            {
                Logger.Debug("GTS or CAT qualifying logic");
                if (currentUtcTime.Hour ==
                    DownloadQualifyingTimes.QTimesList[0] ||
                    currentUtcTime.Hour ==
                    DownloadQualifyingTimes.QTimesList[1])
                {
                    Logger.Debug("Qualifying hour condition meet");
                    if (((currentUtcTime.Minute > DownloadQualifyingTimes.QTimesList[2])
                        && (currentUtcTime.Minute < DownloadQualifyingTimes.QTimesList[3])) || SessionObject.LastLapStartedMinute <= DownloadQualifyingTimes.QTimesList[3])
                    {
                        Logger.Debug("Qualifying minute condition meet");
                        return true;
                    }
```

I hope this illustrates the nature of my question and the problem.

Can you think of a better way to implement this process?  If you need any more information regarding it please don't hesitate to ask.

Edit - Ended up implementing List as per first comment suggestion.

Comment: Create custom types with properties for each piece of information, and use `List<T>` to hold a dynamically sized list of those custom types.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.  So you're saying create a GroupOneType with day1, day 2... dayn types and then just add that to a List<GroupOneType>?

Comment: If you need a dynamic number of days, then no, then I would have a list of days instead / as well. It's hard to be more concrete in my answer since your question is very broad.

Comment: It is very board, I'm sorry about that.  Let me see if I can find my implemented code and add that to the question.

Comment: Edited with the two classes/methods.

Comment: Should only do fileName.Contains("Times") outside the loop and use a hashset for QDaysList.  But other than that looks OK.